# Get the newest date from four different tables using union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query for my MS SQL Server. The query calculates how much of every product are there in the inventory, queued for purchase and sale in every store.

```
SELECT i.no_, 
       s2.location, 
       s2.bincode, 
       s2.inventory, 
       s2.purchase, 
       s2.sale, 
       s2.defbinflag 
FROM   dbo.[kasia$item] AS i WITH (nolock) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT s.itemno, 
                               s.location, 
                               bc.bincode, 
                               Sum(s.inventory) AS Inventory, 
                               Sum(s.purchase)  AS Purchase, 
                               Sum(s.sale)      AS Sale, 
                               bc.defbinflag 
                        FROM   (SELECT [item no_]      AS ItemNo, 
                                       [location code] AS Location, 
                                       Sum(quantity)   AS Inventory, 
                                       0               AS purchase, 
                                       0               AS sale, 
                                       [bin code]      AS BinCode 
                                FROM   dbo.[kasia$warehouse entry] WITH 
                                       (nolock 
                                       ) 
                                WHERE  ( quantity <> 0 ) 
                                GROUP  BY [item no_], 
                                          [location code], 
                                          [bin code] 
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT no_                            AS ItemNo, 
                                       [location code]                AS Location, 
                                       0                              AS Inventory, 
                                       Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) AS purchase, 
                                       0                              AS sale, 
                                       [bin code]                     AS BinCode 
                                FROM   dbo.[kasia$purchase line] WITH ( 
                                       nolock) 
                                WHERE  ( [document type] = 1 ) 
                                       AND ( type = 2 ) 
                                GROUP  BY no_, 
                                          [location code], 
                                          [bin code] 
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT no_                            AS ItemNo, 
                                       [location code]                AS Location, 
                                       0                              AS Inventory, 
                                       0                              AS purchase, 
                                       Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) AS sale, 
                                       [bin code]                     AS BinCode 
                                FROM   dbo.[kasia$sales line] WITH ( 
                                       nolock) 
                                WHERE  ( [document type] = 1 ) 
                                       AND ( type = 2 ) 
                                GROUP  BY no_, 
                                          [location code], 
                                          [bin code] 
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT [item no_]                     AS ItemNo, 
                                       [transfer-from code]           AS Location, 
                                       0                              AS Inventory, 
                                       0                              AS purchase, 
                                       Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) AS sale, 
                                       [transfer-from bin code]       AS BinCode 
                                FROM   dbo.[kasia$transfer line] WITH ( 
                                       nolock) 
                                GROUP  BY [item no_], 
                                          [transfer-from code], 
                                          [transfer-from bin code]) AS s 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                               (SELECT DISTINCT 
                               [item no_], 
                               [location code], 
                               [bin code] AS BinCode, 
                               [default]  AS DefBinFlag 
                                FROM   dbo.[kasia$bin content] 
                                       WITH (nolock) 
                                GROUP  BY [item no_], 
                                          [location code], 
                                          [bin code], 
                                          [default]) AS bc 
                                            ON s.itemno = bc.[item no_] 
                                               AND bc.[location code] = 
                                                   s.location 
                                               AND bc.bincode = s.bincode 
                        WHERE  ( bc.bincode IS NOT NULL ) 
                        GROUP  BY s.itemno, 
                                  s.location, 
                                  bc.bincode, 
                                  bc.defbinflag) AS s2 
                    ON s2.itemno = i.no_
```

But i need need to add the date of the newest entry in one of the four tables

```
[kasia$warehouse entry]
[kasia$purchase line]
[kasia$sales line]
[kasia$transfer line]
```

How could i get a column in the final set with a datetime variable containing the last entry from the four tables? I have not tried to butcher this query which works fine with me trying to get the date which would make it unreadable but the columns are as follows:

```
[kasia$warehouse entry] [Expected Receipt Date]
[kasia$purchase line] [Shipment Date]
[kasia$sales line] [Shipment Date]
[kasia$transfer line] [Registering Date]
```

For now i have this for example as a result:

```
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+------------+
| No_     | location | bincode | inventory | purchase | sale | defbinflag |
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+------------+
| 0035513 | dp       | V14-3   | 3         | 2        | 1    | 1          |
+---------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+------------+
```

I would need to add a column with the date.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are not returning *any* dates from those tables.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: yes! I will edit the post.

Comment: Not a solution, but rather a suggestion. I would break the query into a couple CTEs to make reviewing it easier. Looking at it makes me dizzy. Doing this would also allow you to use a windowing function like `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` to determine ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max([whichever date])` to each union all query and to the query above it and to the top query. Like so:

```
select 
    i.no_
  , s2.location
  , s2.bincode
  , s2.inventory
  , s2.purchase
  , s2.sale
  , s2.defbinflag
  , s2.maxDate
from dbo.[kasia$item] as i with (nolock)
  left join (
    select
        s.itemno
      , s.location
      , bc.bincode
      , Sum(s.inventory) as Inventory
      , Sum(s.purchase) as Purchase
      , Sum(s.sale) as Sale
      , bc.defbinflag
      , max(s.MaxDate) as maxDate
    from (
      select 
          [item no_] as ItemNo
        , [location code] as Location
        , Sum(quantity) as Inventory
        , 0 as purchase
        , 0 as sale
        , [bin code] as BinCode
        , max([Expected Receipt Date]) as MaxDate
      from dbo.[kasia$warehouse entry] with (nolock)
      where (quantity <> 0)
      group by 
          [item no_]
        , [location code]
        , [bin code]

      union all
      select 
          no_ as ItemNo
       , [location code] as Location
       , 0 as Inventory
       , Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) as purchase
       , 0 as sale
       , [bin code] as BinCode
       , max([Shipment Date]) as MaxDate
      from dbo.[kasia$purchase line] with (nolock)
      where ([document type] = 1)
        and (type = 2)
      group by 
         no_
       , [location code]
       , [bin code]

      union all
      select 
          no_ as ItemNo
        , [location code] as Location
        , 0 as Inventory
        , 0 as purchase
        , Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) as sale
        , [bin code] as BinCode
        , max([Shipment Date]) as MaxDate
      from dbo.[kasia$sales line] with (nolock)
      where ([document type] = 1)
        and (type = 2)
      group by 
         no_
       , [location code]
       , [bin code]

      union all
      select 
         [item no_] as ItemNo
       , [transfer-from code] as Location
       , 0 as Inventory
       , 0 as purchase
       , Sum([outstanding qty_ (base)]) as sale
       , [transfer-from bin code] as BinCode
       , max([Registering Date]) as MaxDate
      from dbo.[kasia$transfer line] with (nolock)
      group by [item no_]
       , [transfer-from code]
       , [transfer-from bin code]
    ) as s
  left join (
    select distinct 
        [item no_]
      , [location code]
      , [bin code] as BinCode
      , [default] as DefBinFlag
    from dbo.[kasia$bin content] with (nolock)
    group by [item no_]
      , [location code]
      , [bin code]
      , [default]
    ) as bc 
      on s.itemno = bc.[item no_]
    and bc.[location code] = s.location
    and bc.bincode = s.bincode
   where (bc.bincode is not null)
   group by s.itemno
     , s.location
     , bc.bincode
     , bc.defbinflag
   ) as s2 
   on s2.itemno = i.no_
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar problem by joing same table's max dates and key to get the latest snap shot, one example is added here, same can be used with all tables.

```
 FROM   dbo.[kasia$warehouse entry] warehouse
     JOIN ( select itemno, location, bincode, max(ReceiptDate) lastdate from
           dbo.[kasia$warehouse entry] 
           Group by itemno, location, bincode 
        ) lastreceiptwarehouse
         on lastreceiptwarehouse.itemno = warehouse.itemno 
         and lastreceiptwarehouse.location  = warehouse.location  
         and lastreceiptwarehouse.bincode = warehouse.bincode
          and lastreceiptwarehouse.lastdate= warehouse.ReceiptDate
```